# Prove that the system $\vartheta $ is a ring.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ring-theory

> Prove that the system $\vartheta $ of all finite unions of the form
>   $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\left [a_{i},b_{i}  \right )$ together with the
>   empty set is a ring.

Can anyone help me, how to prove it?

Comment: What are your addition and multiplication operations?

Comment: @JohnDouma I do not have any, or I cannot see them in the book

Comment: Check the section of the book that had this problem. Perhaps there was a similar example of a ring with the operations defined. Also, does your ring have to have a multiplicative identity? These questions must be answered in order to prove that this set is a ring.

Comment: I guess the operations are $\cap$ and $\cup$ as "addition" and "multiplications" respectively.

Comment: @JohnDouma it does not have to have multiplicative identity and as InsideOut said this are the operations

Comment: @Daniel now you know which are the operations, can you get from here?

Comment: @InsideOut Do you mean the other way around? I am assuming the empty set is zero and the empty set would then act as an additive identity under union.

Comment: @InsideOut I do not think so, can you show me how to do it? Maybe just some part, I am trying to learn it

Comment: @JohnDouma That was actually my first idea. But I don't see how to define the inverse with respect the union. I mean, you have a finite union, say $U$, how do you find a finite union $V$ such that $U\cup V=\emptyset?$

Comment: @Daniel You have to specify the operations and they have to be in the book. What book are you using and in what section does this problem appear?

Comment: The emptyset is surely the zero element for $\cup$, but $\cup$ seems more the analog of the multiplications

Comment: @JohnDouma book is written not in english, and it is in the section ring and σ-ring above intervals

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-ring

Comment: Are you trying to prove it is a sigma ring?

Comment: @JohnDouma no, the task is to prove that the system is ring

Comment: what subject are you studying. Or more specifically, can you give us the definition of "ring" being referred to?

Comment: If you actually do mean an algebraic ring, then the answer to the question as asked is "No, this is not a ring" for the simple reason that a ring includes the specification of addition and multiplication operators, and none were given. If the question is actually to *find* operators making this a ring, then there are many, many possibilities, but "union and intersection" are not among them as neither operation has inverses. As $\vartheta$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$, one could simply take a bijection and use it to pull back the real operators.

Comment: There is also a set-theoretic pair of operators that make this a ring (or any other collection of sets that is closed under the operations). However, I would like to confirm what this problem actually means before going any farther. Did you perhaps leave off an important qualifier? For example "a ring of sets" instead just "a ring"? Note that the qualifier may not be given directly in the problem, but instead may be in the context of the problem.